# Georeferencing a Picture having Resolution and a nearly correct BBOX

Tags: georeferencing

Is it possible to get the Boundingbox of a Picture when I know the Resolution, the Height/width in pixels, the sum of Tiles in each row/column and a Coordinate that is in the cornertile but not the corner !

To make it a bit clearer, take a look at that picture: The green things are given(one coordinate in the cornertiles and the resolution) and the red pointer indicates what I want to derive. Each tile is 256x256 pixels.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea ?

yours,
Matthias